# How to avoid memory sharing of variables in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am fetching some rows via an API and assigning the state variables like this

```
this.setState({
    rows: data,
    originalRows: data
})
```

Now I am using these state variables in a filter method where I change the number of rows based on filters.

```
let rows = this.state.rows
filterFunction(){
    //filter logic, editing the variable rows
}
```

The issue is, this also changes the value of `this.state.originalRows`
How to avoid the change that state value?

Comment: can you provide the entire logic of your code being used. So we understand the entire issue and what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share that, company policy. But is it a normal thing in react? Sharing of memory space between variables?

Comment: Some entities are referred to via reference in Javascript, so you don't want to assign them to 2 separate variables. Use the spread operator to create copies of the data, so you don't create multiple references to it. Also, you'll want to follow immutability principles in React when doing state manipulations. `let rows = this.state.rows` is a bad idea, assuming `rows` is an array (or object). You'll want to create a copy of it before manipulating it, e.g. if it's an array: `let rows = [...this.state.rows]`. That way you don't mess with the state when changing the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various ways to achieve this.

```
// rest-spread operator copies values to new object
const obj = {...this.state.originalRows} 

// merges your values to an empty object which works same way
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, this.state.originalRows)
```

If you just write your code as following

```
const obj = this.state.originalRows
```

you just create `reference` to an original variable eg. pointer and change values with in original variable.